# How to automate mobile chat app using selenium with appium?

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium

I have mobile app for chat user, it is similar to what's chat and having some additional features.
How can we automate using selenium webdriver with android appium.

I am thinking for creating two instances but not getting clear idea about it.

Anyone is having any other solutions.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make Appium environment in your system.

Once Appium is installed in your system follow the steps

```
•   Open the APPIUM App
•   Click on ‘Android’ icon at top left
•   In Capabilities section, specify ‘Platform Name’ , ‘Automation Name’, ‘Platform version’ and Device Name’ as required.
•   Click on ‘Settings’ icon at top left
•   Verify the prefilled values i.e. Server address should be ‘127.0.0.1’ and Port as ‘4723’
```

After above steps you need to specify the Package name and Activity name in the code

```
cap1.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.settings");
        cap1.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.settings.Settings");
```

Above mentioned package name and activity name belongs to `SETTINGS` in Android mobile

PASSING PARAMETERS IN YOUR CODE

```
DesiredCapabilities cap1= new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap1.setCapability("deviceName", "Device name");
    cap1.setCapability("platformVersion", "Android version");
    cap1.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap1.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");

    cap1.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.settings");
    cap1.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.settings.Settings");
```

These are the parameters you need to pass in your code to access your app.